# What appcombat version should I use in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I am working with sdk version 19 in Android studio

But what version of appcombat version should I use?

If I see app build gradle, my BuildstoolVersion is 19.1.0 and targetSDK version is also 19.

This is my app build gradle setting as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.seoul.agent.felix.robolectrictest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            // All the usual Gradle options.
            jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4.19.+'
    compile 'com.github.kristofa:mock-http-server:4.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'

}
```

Comment: AppCom**b**at: `Ready... Fight!`

Comment: Use the **latest appcompat library**: currently 23.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need any support library in you project because your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are the same.

Support libraries are meant to add new features to older android versions. There are currently six versions of the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html):

- v4
- v7
- v8
- v13
- v14
- v17

**But remember:** Support library version 7 is not the newer version of 4 and 8 is not the newer version of 7. Instead each version includes components that were added in the android release of this version-number.

Example: Android Version 3.0 (API Level 11) was release with the new feature called "Fragments". In order to be able to use fragments in Android before 3.0 they introduced [v4 Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4).

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 19 and your `minSdkVersion` is 10 and you want to use fragments, than you would need to use the classes from the v4 support library to make them available on all phones.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Read better the question: But what version of appcombat version should I use? The are only 1 appcompat support library.

Comment: thanks version was a problem. It was done after sdk version is lowered